# How to capitalize the first letter of a word from a list that is preceded by a word ending in punctuation? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a quick program in Python that translates from English to pig latin. I have finished the pig latin part where the output is a string of translated words. The punctuation works properly and is included with each word:

```
input= This is a sentence. Now it is in pig latin.   
output= ['isthay','isay','away','entencesay.','ownay','itay','isay','inay','igpay','atinlay.']
```

I can join these using ' '.join(...) but I am looking for a way to capitalize the first letter of the words that follow words ending in '*.:?!*' as well as the very first letter.

I have tried many different things as well as similar questions on this website but I haven't found exactly what I'm looking for.

I am very inexperienced with this so any answers would help.
Thank you.

Note. I am ***not*** looking to capilatise the first letter of every word!

Comment: You don't want the accepted answer in the dup, but the second one.

Comment: It's right there in the bar at the top of the page. Underneath where it says "This question already has an answer here:" is a link to where the answer is.

Comment: add an example of the output you want.